# AppStore, I have an app in review, can I change it manually released by myself from automatically release?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I want to check everything is OK before it released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do it when you are uploading the app for App Store. Otherwise if it is in review then you can't do anything with the binary uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try to contact them and ask them to change this (through the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of the iTunes Connect home page). But they might take time to respond and they might say no, so this is probably not a good idea.  The only way you can be sure is to reject your binary and then submit it again and choose the option you want.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reject the binary, modify the release date to some date far off in the future and resubmit unfortunately. Once the app is approved you can set the release date and release it. I don't think you are going to be able to download the app once it is approved unless it is available on the store though, so you will still need to test from you current local build anyway.